# Extracting Table Data from RTF files in Python

Tags: python, rtf

I need to extract table data from RTF files, but i cannot seem to get any solutions with regards to this. Can anyone suggest a solution or have done this before and is willing to show me dawae? I am currently exploring to change what i define as start and end of table to something like a circumflex.

i only derived the start of the table which is something like

```
\par \ltrrow}
```

but for the end of the table, i cannot seem to find a suitable syntax....

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of converting rtf format to plaintext using regex

```
import re

text = r"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Shell Dlg 2;}{\f1\fnil MS Shell Dlg 2;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;} {\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\tx720\cf1\f0\fs20 can u send me info for the call plsssss\f1\par }"

x = re.sub(r"{\*?\\.+(;})|\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\s?{\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?|\s?}\s?", "", text)
print(x)
```